# Remote desktop protocol from Windows that works smooth both for Linux and Windows clients

Tags: linux, windows-10, remote-desktop

I connect to my office Windows machine with RDP. It works smooth on Windows (but still held by the poor internet connection), but connecting from a Linux machine, it is not usable at all.

How can I even things out so both clients have a remote desktop experience at least OK?

Believe it or not, the internet connection we have at work gives me 500kbps at best, more often 300 is good.

If two workers are connected at the same time, don't even think using your remote desktop.

Comment: in that case a text terminal is better. Just ssh into the remote machine

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com)? I have always used this on both machines and it runs well.